# How to extract certain fields from json output using jq?

Tags: json, jq

Using jq, how can I extract the host, name, and date_happened fields from the json output below?  I read another thread regarding this here at stackoverflow, but still can't seem to get it.

-Thanks

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "alert_type": "success",
            "children": [
                {
                    "alert_type": "error",
                    "date_happened": 1573502725,
                    "id": "5188183926379101887"
                },
                {
                    "alert_type": "success",
                    "date_happened": 1573503145,
                    "id": "5188190972457497744"
                }
            ],
            "comments": [],
            "date_happened": 1573502725,
            "device_name": null,
            "host": "i-0e4b192579a9b423b",
            "id": 5188183933173874377,
            "is_aggregate": true,
            "priority": "normal",
            "resource": "/api/v1/events/5188183933173874377",
            "source": "Monitor Alert",
            "tags": [
                "autoscaling_group:app2_backend-asg-prod",
                "availability-zone:us-east-1b",
                "datadog-agent:true",
                "environment:prod",
                "host:i-0e6b192579a9b423b",
                "iam_profile:app2_backend_instance_profile",
                "image:ami-2769055d",
                "instance-type:m4.large",
                "monitor",
                "name:app2_backend-prod",
                "region:us-east-1",
                "role:app2_backend",
```

Comment: You should post complete, valid JSON and show your expected output – plus, ideally, what you've tried and how its result was different from what you expected. Complete/valid JSON is important so people can test their answers.

Comment: Thank you.  Using the same JSON text as in my original post, and using your example, I am not getting the "name" field which should be app2_backend-prod.  I am getting the other two fields though.

<events.json jtc -w'<host>l' -w'<name>l' -w'<host>l[-1]<date_happened>l'
"i-0e4b192579a9b423b"
1573502725

Comment: it's because your `name` is not really the JSON field (label), it's part of the JSON string value. If you like to match it in the JSON string value, you need to use regex matching: **`<file.json jtc -w'<host>l' -w'<host>l[-1]<date_happened>l' -w'<^name:>R'`**.

Comment: and if you like to match the value w/o `name:` prefix, then use it like this: **`<file.json jtc -w'<host>l' -w'<host>l[-1]<date_happened>l' -w'<^name:(.*)>R' -T'{{$1}}'`**.

Comment: How would I get the "Status" value of OK?

],
            "text": "%%%\nQuery recovered on host:i-0e4b192579a9b423b,name:app2_backend-prod \n\n![snapshot](https://p.datadoghq.com/snapshot/view/dd-snapshots-prod/org_125488/2019-11-11/87f3217c72423a6ba45a1e8e096bb07ff02c08f3.png)\n\n{{#is_alert}}  \nStatus: Problem\nHost:         {{name.name}} \nHost ID:    {{host.name}}\nHost IP:     {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_alert}}\n\n{{#is_warning}}  \nStatus: Problem\nHost:        {{name.name}} \nHost ID:     {{host.name}}\nHost IP:     {{host.ip}}\n{{/is_warning}}\n\n\n{{#is_recovery}} \nStatus: OK\nHost:

Comment: The comments section is growing too big, if you like - submit a separate question tagged with `jtc` and I elaborate there in the answer section

Comment: Thank you I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

The jq filter:

```
.events[]
| [.host, 
   (.tags[] | select( test("^name:") ) | sub("name:";"")),
   .date_happened]
```

produces

```
 ["i-0e4b192579a9b423b","app2_backend-prod",1573502725]
```